# Extract the lowest value from an attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am not to sure if this is possible?  What I am looking to do is.

1 - I have polygon and point data. I want to use the polygon to select the point data that falls within in the radius of the polygon.

2- The point data has attributes linked to a common id. I want to then extract the lowest value from that common ID then place it into a field in the polygon.

E.g.  point data looks like

```
field1 200C063D094B09   field2 BLSK field3 2345
field1 200C063D094B09   field2 CDMN field3 2456
field1 200C063D094B09   field2 GTNG field3 2432
```

Then I want to add Field 1 and 3 to the polygon.

Is this even possible? I am not good at scripting so this would be manual

Comment: Yes this is possible but the solution depends on whether you are doing this manually or  through a script.  Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Join by Location (Summary)` tool with the "min" summary type.

[image]

For points that fall within each polygon, this tool will add the minimum values from fields 1 and 3 to that polygon. It creates a new layer, which by default is a temporary layer. Be sure to save the temporary layer as a permanent layer before closing the project.